# Is it "bad practice" to require() within a gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp, require

*TL;DR*

Is it considered bad practice to `require()` within the body of a task instead of at the "top of the file"?

---

We were having an issue where gulp would take 10, 20 ... 60 seconds to start, before even starting the task it was asked to run. Our gulpfile requires around a dozen other files, each with 1..many tasks. In each of those required files, we were `require()`'ing *all* of the packages *any* of the tasks within the file may need. I fixed the slow startup by moving the `require()`s into the specific tasks that need that package. Now gulp's start-up time is a handful of milliseconds. Score.

It seems like I've never seen examples of people using `require()` like this, from with a task's body. Is there a reason for that (am I missing something)?

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with `require`ing your modules later. It just tends to be easier to see what you're working with when it's all loaded up front.